# Dozens of errors, most of which have to do with math mode or enumerate lists, in extremely short document

Tags: math-mode, errors, lists, enumerate

I'm very new to LaTeX, and I just switched to using TeXMaker and MiKTeX. I just created this extremely short document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\title{AP Stats Test Revision: Ch. 7}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{1)}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \[${\sigma_Y}=\|b\|\sigma_X$\] \dagger \[${\sigma_Y}=75(7.09)=531.75$\] \dagger C
    \end{enumerate}
\section*{7)}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [${W_T}={W_1}+{W_2}+{W_3}+{W_4}}$ ${\mu_W_T}={\mu_{W_1}}+{\mu_{W_2}}+{\mu_{W_3}}+{\mu_{W_4}}$]    
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

Which results in these errors:

[image: Errors, part 1]
[image: Errors, part 2]

Here's the full log file:
https://pastebin.com/h8JDTnt7

Any help would be appreciated - thank you so much! :D

(let me know if there's any better way to upload the error messages and the log file!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It seems, as if you are using an evironment for display formulae (`\[...\]` is the short version of `\begin{displaymath}`) and within that math environment you have `$...$` which  usually is used to type inline math formulae.

Comment: It seems also that the math in section*{7)} are put into [...] in place of \[...\], making it an an optional label in the list.

Answer (score 5):

The first error is important, other errors may be only consequences of previous. I describe how to deal with errors in your document step by step.

First error shows:

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.17         \item \[${
                       \sigma_Y}=\|b\|\sigma_X$\] \dagger \[${\sigma_Y}=75(7...
```

You opened display math by `\[` which TeX internally realizes as opening by `$$`. There cannot be opened single `$` (internal math mode) inside display math mode. So, we remove this `$` (and the second one after `\sigma_X` too) and run TeX again. Now the first error is:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.17 ...\item \[{\sigma_Y}=\|b\|\sigma_X\] \dagger
                                                   \[${\sigma_Y}=75(7.09)=53...
```

The report of your input line is always broken to two lines and the important
point where the error occurs is always shown at the end of the first line. We see `\dagger` here. The control sequence `\dagger` is declared internally by `\mathchardef` TeX primitive and it is allowed to be prtinting only in the math (or display math) mode. But we are in text mode now. That is the reason of this error. So, we open and close internal math mode using `$\dagger$`. And run TeX again. First error now is:

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.17 ...[{\sigma_Y}=\|b\|\sigma_X\] $\dagger$ \[${
                                                  \sigma_Y}=75(7.09)=531.75$...
```

Aha, we have previous experience with this error, so we remove two next dollars and run TeX again:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.17 ...er$ \[{\sigma_Y}=75(7.09)=531.75\] \dagger
                                                   C
```

There is second `\dagger` with the same problem as previous, replace it by `$\dagger$`. Run TeX again.

```
! Argument of \@item has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.21 ...    \item [${W_T}={W_1}+{W_2}+{W_3}+{W_4}}
                                                  $ ${\mu_W_T}={\mu_{W_1}}+{...
```

We see the point where the error occurs and we used a construction `\item[...]` but there is not balanced text inside the `[...]`. TeX principle is: all parameters must be balanced text, i.e. the `{` and `}` must match. But there is `}` which doesn't match. Remove it and run TeX again.

```
! Double subscript.
<argument> ...}={W_1}+{W_2}+{W_3}+{W_4}$ ${\mu _W_
                                                  T}={\mu _{W_1}}+{\mu _{W_2...
l.21 ..._1}}+{\mu_{W_2}}+{\mu_{W_3}}+{\mu_{W_4}}$]
```

TeX doesn't allow double superscript. It means we must use `{\mu_W}_T` instead `{\mu _W_T}` (where the braces and space are irrelevant) and run TeX again. Now, the document is without errors and TeX prints exactly, what you write. But IMHO, your intend was somewhat different, but this is another story.
Note, for example, that you use `\[...\]` in section 1) but only `[...]` in section 7). The first one creates math in display math mode, the second one is a parameter of the `\item` macro.

This example shows that also LaTeX users should know TeX itself, because errors are typically reported by TeX not by LaTeX. The knowledge about TeX modes, balanced text, to-be-read-again principle etc. are very useful. Without them LaTeX users cannot understand the error messages reported by TeX. Unfortunately, TeX principles are typically not mentioned in LaTeX manuals, so LaTeX user without knowledge about TeX is lost.

Moreover, some graphical interfaces for making TeX documents doesn't show error messages properly. Note that the crucial point of the error is always at the breaking point of the reported line. Check if your graphical interface respects this principle.

Comment: A very good and thorough explanation! +1!

Answer (score 2):

This document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\title{AP Stats Test Revision: Ch. 7}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{1)}
    \begin{enumerate}

    \item \[{\sigma_Y}=\|b\|\sigma_X\] $\dagger$ \[{\sigma_Y}=75(7.09)=531.75\] $\dagger C$
    \end{enumerate}
\section*{7)}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [${W_T}={W_1}+{W_2}+{W_3}+{W_4}$ ${\mu_{W_T}}={\mu_{W_1}}+{\mu_{W_2}}+{\mu_{W_3}}+{\mu_{W_4}}$]    
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

compiles without errors. But I doubt that it will create whatever you want to create (since you did not tell us). Among other problems,

- you use `$` signs in `\[...\]` environments;
- there was a double subscript (`\mu_W_T`);
- you used the `\dagger` command in text mode.